# Edebug step-in throws error

Tags: edebug

```
(error "You must be before a list form")
```

I instrument a function in emacs. Now, this function is calling some other function. I try to step into this new function using the shortcut key `i` (`step-into-function`). Emacs throws an error, with this message -

```
You must be before a list form
```

The irony is, for forms emacs evaluate, it always places the cursor at the end of a form like this,
[image: cursor-position]
So, why doesn't edebug `step-in` work properly?

Since my cursor keeps blinking, i have put a black mark for cursor instead of the usual white mark.

Comment: Did you try doing what the error message suggests? (I.e. moving the point before the parenthesis which surround the function you want to step into?)

Comment: the point is controlled by the debugger... user doesn't move the point... even if the user moves the point, the debugger will take the control from the place where it left...

Comment: I just tried and I can move the point without a problem, and the debugger will step into the function which is called immediately after the point. I'm using Emacs 25.0.50.1 though, it could've been different before, but, to the best of my memory you could always just move the point in the debug mode and step into the selected function. Maybe you were trying to step into `setq`? Which is defined in C code, and isn't really a function.

Comment: my issue is seen with elisp coded functions. i used `edebug-defun` to instrument a function and then move form by form using `next shortcut` letter - `n` inside the instrumented function? are you using the same method?

Comment: and do i need to instrument the function manually that i plan to step into?

Comment: Nope, I actually press `SPC` (step). And no, you don't need to instrument the function you step into.

Comment: me too, cant step-into by `SPC` , have to `edebug-defun` every function I want to. I am using emacs 24.5,OSX,ergoemacs-mode.

Comment: Forgot to say, I also tried `i`, did not work either.